# MS Access SQL IIF if false then return old value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a question I am doing an Update query and using the IIF function in the process:

```
Update someTable as tab Set tab.[field1] = "new filed1 value", tab.[field2] = IIF
(
tab[field2] = "some value" , "New value",IIF
(
tab.[field2] = tab.[field2],tab.[field2]))

)) Where tab.[field1] = "Old field 1 value"
```

With the above query I wanto to change field2 to "New Value" if it equals to "some value" but if it doesn't then I don't want to change it (or put the same value as it was like the above)

So my question is would the below line in the above query work as expected?

```
IIF
    (
    tab.[field2] = tab.[field2],tab.[field2]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression is too complicated.  This is what you want:

```
Update someTable as tab
    Set tab.[field1] = "new filed1 value",
        tab.[field2] = IIF(tab.[field2] = "some value", tab.[field2])
    Where tab.[field1] = "Old field 1 value";
```

Comment: so if I put tab.[field2] as a parameter into whichever single row function it returns the current value of the field? I cannot check at the moment:( If it is so then that is the answer I was looking for:) Thanks

Comment: @RobertMazurowski . . . Yes.  The shorthand is that the values on the right hand side come from the *old* record and those on the left hand side from the *new* record.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I mean that table.[field] on its own in Single Row functions (like IIF) returns the value of this field from the row